# Apache ShardingSphere IN statements routing

Tags: java, database, jdbc, sharding

I'm implementing the TableRuleConfiguration in Apache ShardingSphere and I'm having problems with IN statements, I've noticed that matching the strategy with shardingValue by using OR condition in the doSharding method override (match at least one value) won't route to the default strategy when the match is incomplete (Only one of many values is matched) while repacing IN with multiple ORs will route to the default strategy as well when at least one doesn't match any strategy.

I've tried adding the default strategy when the patch is incomplete but when routing table I don't know whether the datasource matches as well since they are handled separately, so I get more matches than needed.

How is this supposed to be handled?

Comment: Why is this tagged with `[mysql]`?

Comment: removed tag, could appy to any dialect